# How do you interrogate someone in Another Case Solved?

Tags: another-case-solved

How do you interrogate a person on another case solved? I have no idea how to do that when I'm narrowing down my suspects.

Answer (score 1):

People that can be interrogated are displayed as black silhouettes, as [this site states it](http://www.gamezebo.com/2014/02/28/another-case-solved-walkthrough-cheats-strategy-guide/), while on the match-3 board:

> The next witness to be interrogated is also displayed as a silhouette,
>   with a speech bubble above their head.  This bubble contains a number
>   and icon: it shows what they need in order to answer your questions.